# Display status of toggle switch in vuetify data-table

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm complet stuck and can't see to fix my issue. My goal is to display the status of the toggle switch in my Vuetify data-table.

It seems to work but each time I change the toggle switch the status of all lines get changed. And this isn't the idea. It needs to be for each specific line.
Small side note: Instead of "true" and "false" I would prefer "On" and "off"

When you propose a solution, would you mind also telling me what I'm doing wrong as this is the only way I will learn.

```
   <template>
  <v-card>
    <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="companies">
      <template v-slot:top>
        <v-toolbar flat>
          <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="850px">
            <template v-slot:activator="{on}">
              <v-btn color="primary" dark class="mb-2" v-on="on">Nieuw bedrijf</v-btn>
            </template>

            <v-card>
              <v-card-title>
                <span class="headline">{{ formTitle }}</span>
              </v-card-title>

              <v-card-text>
                <v-container>
                  <v-row>
                    <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="6">
                      <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.name" label="Bedrijfsnaam"></v-text-field>
                    </v-col>
                  </v-row>
                  <v-row>
                    <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="6">
                      <v-switch v-model="switch1" flat :label="`Switch 1: ${switch1.toString()}`"></v-switch>
                    </v-col>
                  </v-row>
                </v-container>
              </v-card-text>

              <v-card-actions>
                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="close">Annuleer</v-btn>
                <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="save">Bewaar</v-btn>
              </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
          </v-dialog>
        </v-toolbar>

        <v-divider class="mt-3" />
      </template>
      <template v-slot:item.portaal="{}">
        <v-chip color="primary" v-text="switch1" dark></v-chip>
      </template>
      <template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
        <v-icon small class="mr-2" @click="editItem(item)">mdi-pencil</v-icon>
        <v-icon small text @click="showDeleteDialog(item)">mdi-delete</v-icon>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
    <v-dialog v-model="dialogDelete" max-width="500px">
      <v-card>
        <v-card-title>Delete</v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>Weet je zeker dat je {{itemToDelete.name}} wenst te verwijderen?</v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
          <v-btn color="primary" text @click="dialogDelete = false">Annuleer</v-btn>
          <v-btn color="primary" text @click="deleteItem()">Verwijderen</v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
      </v-card>
    </v-dialog>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

Script

```
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    headers: [
      { text: "Bedrijfsnaam", align: "start", value: "name" },
      { text: "Portaal", value: "portaal", sortable: false },
      { text: "Actions", value: "actions", sortable: false }
    ],
    companies: [],
    switch1: false,
    dialog: false,
    dialogDelete: false,
    itemToDelete: {},
    editedIndex: -1,
    editedItem: {
      name: ""
    }
  }),

  computed: {
    formTitle() {
      return this.editedIndex === -1
        ? "Nieuw bedrijf"
        : "Bewerk " + this.editedItem.name;
    }
  },

  watch: {
    dialog(val) {
      val || this.close();
    }
  },

  created() {
    this.initialize();
  },

  methods: {
    initialize() {
      this.companies = [
        {
          name: "Bogaert SCA",
          phone: "+32 50 64 68 62",
          email: "marie34@daems.net",
          website: "www.daems.net",
          to: "http://www.bloomford.be",
          location: "Brugge"
        },
        {
          name: "Thomas BVBA",
          phone: "+32 9 654 97 31 64",
          email: "tess.claessens@charlier.org",
          website: "www.charlier.org",
          to: "http://www.rsca.be",
          location: "Gent"
        }
      ];
    },

    switch1(newValue) {
      this.headers[5].value = newValue;
    },

    editItem(item) {
      this.editedIndex = this.companies.indexOf(item);
      this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item);
      this.dialog = true;
    },

    showDeleteDialog(item) {
      this.itemToDelete = item;
      this.dialogDelete = !this.dialogDelete;
    },
    deleteItem() {
      const index = this.companies.indexOf(this.itemToDelete);
      this.companies.splice(index, 1);
      this.dialogDelete = false;
    },

    close() {
      this.dialog = false;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem);
        this.editedIndex = -1;
      }, 300);
    },

    save() {
      if (this.editedIndex > -1) {
        Object.assign(this.companies[this.editedIndex], this.editedItem);
      } else {
        this.companies.push(this.editedItem);
      }
      this.close();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Very confusing the way the switch model is switch1 instead of portaal. Also why is switch1 a method and a data property? Why not just bind the switch to portaal? https://codeply.com/p/tlXizKP4dD

Comment: Thank you very very much for, again, your excellent comments and tips

Comment: @Codeply-er, how would you solve it?

Comment: Yes, thank you. But now the status isn't shown in the dialog and the status names aren't "On" instead of "true" and "Off" instead of "False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind the switch to `portaal`. Also `switch1` should not be a method and a data property. The label doesn't have to be the same as the modal. just use a method for the on/off label...

```
   <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="companies">
            <template v-slot:top>
                <v-toolbar flat>
                    <v-dialog v-model="dialog">
                        <template v-slot:activator="{on}">
                            <v-btn color="primary" dark class="mb-2" v-on="on">Nieuw bedrijf</v-btn>
                        </template>
                        <v-card>
                            <v-card-title>
                                <span class="headline">{{ formTitle }}</span>
                            </v-card-title>
                            <v-card-text>
                                <v-container>
                                    <v-row>
                                        <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="6">
                                            <v-text-field v-model="editedItem.name" label="Bedrijfsnaam"></v-text-field>
                                        </v-col>
                                    </v-row>
                                    <v-row>
                                        <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="6">
                                            <v-switch v-model="editedItem.portaal" flat :label="switchLabel(editedItem.portaal)"></v-switch>
                                        </v-col>
                                    </v-row>
                                </v-container>
                            </v-card-text>
                            <v-card-actions>
                                <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                                <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="close">Annuleer</v-btn>
                                <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="save">Bewaar</v-btn>
                            </v-card-actions>
                        </v-card>
                    </v-dialog>
                </v-toolbar>
                <v-divider class="mt-3" />
            </template>
            <template v-slot:item.portaal="{ item }">
                <v-chip color="primary" v-text="switchLabel(item.portaal||false)" dark></v-chip>
            </template>
            <template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
                <v-icon small class="mr-2" @click="editItem(item)">mdi-pencil</v-icon>
                <v-icon small text @click="showDeleteDialog(item)">mdi-delete</v-icon>
            </template>
   </v-data-table>

   switchLabel (bool) {
       return bool?'on':'off'
   },
```

https://codeply.com/p/tlXizKP4dD